# examples of non-unique factorisation in cyclotomic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

I was looking into cyclotomic extensions of the natural numbers, and I found that extending the naturals with the 23rd root of unity caused the ring to no longer be a UFD. In other words, there now exists numbers that could be factorised into irreducibles in two different ways. Is there a simple example of when this occurs?

Answer (score 4):

Marcus, Number fields, page 11 (exercise 29)